# Concatenating columns not returning full results

Tags: sql, sql-server, concatenation

I have a table that I want to concatenate 4 columns together; 2 of them are integers, 1 text & 1 date.

I have joined them together by casting the integers to varchar & formatting the date. But I have an example where the last item is not being shown

```
SELECT 
    CAST(CONTRACT_ID VARCHAR(15)) + '-' +
    CAST(CONTRACT_TYPE AS VARCHAR(15))  + '-' +
    GENDER + '-' + FORMAT(DOB, 'yyyy') AS UNIQUE_ID
```

There are 4 rows which should have the same output, then they differ.

```
- 12345678-70-M -1948
- 12345678-70-M
- 12345678-70-M
- 12345678-70-M
```

But when run as results to text, the correct results return

```
- 12345678-70-M -1948
- 12345678-70-M -1948
- 12345678-70-M -1948
- 12345678-70-M -1948
```

This isn't a visual error within the grid, because if I do a filter on it it will only return the 1 row.

I did notice though, if I cast the gender to `varchar(1)`, the results do work.
Could there be a hidden character at the end of the gender field that is causing the issue.

It seems to be working fine 99% of the time.

Comment: Please show the definition of the tables and sample data.

Answer (score 1):

Try the below query. Here the DOB column data type is `DateTime` and the value is only for the sample i.e., current date.

```
create table test (CONTRACT_ID VARCHAR(15),
CONTRACT_TYPE VARCHAR(15),
GENDER Char(1),
DOB Datetime
)

 Insert into test Values
('12345678', '70', 'M', Getdate()),
('12345678', '70', 'M', Getdate()),
('12345678', '70', 'M', Getdate()),
('12345678', '70', 'M', Getdate())

Select * from test

SELECT 
    CAST(CONTRACT_ID as VARCHAR(15)) + '-' +
    CAST(CONTRACT_TYPE AS VARCHAR(15))  + '-' +
    GENDER + '-' + FORMAT(DOB, 'yyyy') AS UNIQUE_ID
    from test
```

[image]

Here is the [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=86bda8d9068ba8880fb99bd2c49c582c) demo.

Answer (score 0):

This suggests that there are spaces in `GENDER` -- or some other character.  Try this:

```
SELECT CONCAT(CONTRACT_ID, '-', CONTRACT_TYPE, '-',
              LTRIM(RTRIM(GENDER)), '-', YEAR(DOB)
             ) AS UNIQUE_ID
```

Another possibility is that `GENDER` has some character such as a newline at the end.  It looks like the first character is correct, so:

```
SELECT CONCAT(CONTRACT_ID, '-', CONTRACT_TYPE, '-',
              LEFT(GENDER, 1), '-', YEAR(DOB)
             ) AS UNIQUE_ID
```

Comment: Thanks for the concat example. For some reason I was thinking concat was only 2 variables at a time.

As for the Gender `LEN(LTRIM(RTRIM(GENDER)))'  still gives me a length of 2 for the rows that don't work, although for the row that does work, it returns a length of one, but still includes a space (when the trims are not included)